# Where is the documentation for TWebBrowserEx in Delphi XE?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I just discovered TWebBrowserEx in the Delphi XE source.  When I google it, I get zero hits!  Anyone have insight on where this component came from, and on what the purpose is?

Comment: Someone (you?) made a copy of ShDocVw.pas and modified it?

Comment: Turns out not eh.   Sometimes my hunches are way off.

Answer (score 4):

You can find the source in $(BDS)\Source\Internet\WebBrowserEx.pas. If you open that file, there is a large section of comments at the top giving links to the documentation for the interfaces inside.

Comment: OP said: "I just discovered TWebBrowserEx in the Delphi XE source".

Comment: @David, I know. That part was for you and @Warren. :) The part for the OP was about opening the source file and seeing the doc links.

Comment: @Ken Where do the links take you? MSDN?

Comment: @David, yes. There's also a little sample code. If you want, I can post some of the links in an edit to my answer.

Comment: @Ken No need. Can't believe Troy didn't just read the source. Brian Cryer's website is still the best documentation around for this though.

Comment: There is a whole LOT of stuff in \Source\Internet that I have never touched.

Comment: It's a huge file!  Reading the source wouldn't very easily tell me where this component came from, and on what the purpose is.  I wanted to know *why* it's in the VCL source, not the specifics on exactly what it can do.

Answer (score 2):

The component is usually called TWebBrowser – no doubt this is a variant.  Perhaps they renamed it to avoid clashes with existing TWebBrowser components.

TWebBrowser is an OCX wrapper around [IWebBrowser2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752127%28VS.85%29.aspx).  It's very hard to imagine that TWebBrowserEx is implemented in any other way.

The documentation is on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752127%28VS.85%29.aspx) but you'll get better hits searching for TWebBrowser. The best source of information is [Brian Cryer's site](http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/delphi/twebbrowser/index.htm).

Note that once you get into programming the DOM (through the `Document` property) it becomes highly dynamic and so what documentation there is takes quite a bit of getting used to if you are used to more static class interfaces.

**UPDATE**

According to @jachguate, TWebBrowserEx derives from TWebBrowser and adds a bunch of extra interfaces.  I don't believe this changes anything substantial in the answer. The documentation sources are still going to be as listed above.

Comment: Do you have such a class declared in any file in the VCL sources? I don't.

Comment: @Warren No I don't, but I've only got 2010. Whatever it is, it's bound to be IWebBrowser2 though isn't it?

Comment: So properly speaking, it's not even a real Delphi thing, and thus, it's hardly surprising it isn't documented.  It is technically possible that someone made a wrapper for CEF (ChromeEmbeddedFramework), aka WebKit, and called it that. :-)

Comment: It is documented. I give the link in my answer.

Comment: This reminds me of Bilbo's riddle: What's it gots in its unitses?

Comment: @Warren <pedantic>That was Gollum's riddle!</pedantic>  If you do a websearch you can find traces. It's a mystery!

Comment: Here is someone working on something by that name:  http://www.delphipages.com/forum/showthread.php?t=108832

Comment: @Warren unlikely to be in XE (!) and anyway, all roads lead back to IWebBrowser2!

Comment: @Warren P, many people used to `TFooEx` convention, meaning it `ex`tends original `t`ype named `Foo`

Comment: @Warren, @David: there's a unit named internet\WebBrowserEx.pas on my Delphi XE Enterprise upgrade 1 source folder.  Inside it is a class named TWebBrowserEx, deriving from TWebBrowser and implementing a buch of interfaces. Are you sure you don't have it?

Comment: @jachguate: I have it in XE Professional, too. It has tons of comments in it with URLs to documentation.

Comment: @jachguate D2010 Pro, much cut-down installation. I don't have it. Does it offer much beyond TWebBrowser?

Comment: @David, I'm not a TWebBrowser frequent user, but this class is huge, I count 56 properties and 14 events, maybe a hundred of fields and lot of protected methods, with interfaces like IDocHostUIHandler, IServiceProvider, IOleCommandTarget.

Comment: Auxiliary classes defined there includes TWebBrowserEvents2Dispatch, TWndEventDispatch, TIFrameDocEventDispatch, TDocEventDispatch, TWebBrowserEventDispatch, THTMLElementEventDispatch, TWebBrowserServiceProvider, TEventDispatchEx, TCustomWebBrowserCommandUpdater, TWebBrowserCommandUpdater

Comment: Ah. I see. I did a search using delphi find in files, and it didn't find it, because I only searched the VCL folder, not the whole sources folder. My oops.

Answer (score 2):

The one that is installed into the IDE for use at designtime is called TWebBrowser, and it is implemented in SHDocVw.pas.

I *thought* there is no such class name as TWebBrowserEx in any file in Delphi XE VCL source folder. <strike>What file are you looking at and where is it located?</strike>

You might be interested in the TEmbeddedWB component from www.bsalsa.com. I found that it works a lot better for me than the standard TWebBrowser.

Update: So it does exist.  Whoa. It seems to be an inner class defined inside this unit, used as a field inside TCustomWebBrowserComponent, which seems to be a base class you would extend.

Comment: I have a source file named internet\WebBrowserEx.pas.  Delphi XE Enterprise, Update 1.

Comment: Okay. For some reason Delphi find-in-files failed me.

Comment: thanks for mentioning TCustomWebBrowserComponent.  I did a search on this and found the unit WBComp which has TCustomHTMLEditDesigner and I found the IEActions class which has actions like TWebBrowserRefresh.  I also found the ASPBehavior class.  I think this is the web browser used in the IDE for the HTML designer.